# ESXI/CentOs Cannot connect to internet

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi

I installed CentoS on a vm. I have use the netinstall. During the install i configure my network with:

- IP Adress: 195.154.32.33
- NETMASK: 255.255.255.255
- GateWay: * same Gateway of my esxi server*

Internet was working and everything worked with my install.

I reboot the server and now i d'ont have internet.

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
BROADCAST="195.154.32.33"
NETMASK="255.255.255.255"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
GATEWAY=same as my esxi server
HWADDR="00:50:56:00:54:08"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
IPADDR: 195.154.32.33
```

What's wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Your netmask is incorrect. Try: 255.255.255.0, or whatever your ESXi server's mask is set to.

Comment: I try 255.255.255.0, then i service network restart (And try a reboot, just in case). Doesn't work.

Comment: You need to sort out what the correct networking settings are for your network - stop flailing around and trying random settings and actually learn how this stuff works.

Comment: In the esxi config it's 255.255.255.0 for ipv4. Do you have some tips or another idea ? I think my networking settings are correct. When it doesn't work i try another configuration. How can i learn how this stuff work if i don't flailing arround and ask for help ?

Comment: `How can i learn how this stuff work if i don't flailing arround and ask for help ?`  By actually learning the fundamentals.  If you learn the fundamentals, you won't need to flail around and ask for help, because you will just know the proper configuration, or be able to figure it on your own, with minimal effort.

Comment: I have a problem with a network config. I ask for some help to figure out what's wrong. I'm a newbie so i can't have help from other person ? Thank's to help me to learn ! Thank's to give some useful link to understand my error.I'm so glad to be part of community who don't help newbies.